# Getting Run-Time error when trying to Load a file : Vector subscript out of range?

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

Im making a program for class that manages a Hotel.  I have a function that saves all the current information in the program.  But When I try to load back that information, the program crashes and says: Vector subscript out of range.  I tried debugging, and I found the area where the problem should be (I think I used the debugger correctly?), but im not getting any compiler errors, so I cant figure out whats wrong. Any suggestions?

```
void Customer::fromFileString(string data)
{
vector<string> field=tokenize(data);
name=field[0];
phoneNumber=field[1]; //<--- DEBUGGER SAYS ERROR IS IN THIS LINE
ccNumber=field[2];
customerID=stringToInt(field[3]);
int numberOfrooms = stringToInt(field[4]);
for(int i=0;i<numberOfrooms;i++)
{
    roomsCheckedInto.push_back(stringToInt(field[5+i]));
}
}
```

Here is the tokenize function

```
vector<string> tokenize(string com)
{
istringstream is(com);
vector<string> vs;
string s;
while(!is.eof())
{
    is>>s;
    vs.push_back(s);
}
return vs;
}
```

Comment: It is likely that your function tokenize is only returning a vector<string> containing only a single string, could you post the code for this function so we can tell you what is likely to be the error

Comment: @EdChum ok I added the tokenize function

Comment: I figured it out, I had to adjust the tokenizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that `field[1]` doesn't exist. So for whatever reason, your `tokenize` function is returning a vector of length 1.